# Using wildcard for $ie.Document.getElementById

Tags: internet-explorer-9, powershell-3.0

How to use wild card for

```
$value = $ie.Document.getElementById("*R2:1").value
```

the above one doesn't work and i want to search by ID containing "R2:1" irrespective of prefix.

and also how can i get value by using 2 filters like

```
$ie.Document.getElementById("*R2:1")
$ie.Document.getElementByTitle("crated by:*").value
```

using these 2 filters i need to get the value.

can anyone please help me with this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try iterating thru it and search:

```
$elements = $ie.Document.documentelement.all
foreach ($element in $elements){
    if ($element.id -like '*R2:1*' )
    {
        print "Found!"
    }

    if ($element.id -like '*created by*' )
    {
        print "Found!"
    }

}
```

Comment: This is Taking long time to process.